# R source function convert to Python

Tags: python, r, import

in my understanding, source in R is import and execute the code from source code. does Python has the equivalent function to import and execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can import code/modules/etc using `import` in python. Here are some resources to get you started:

- https://medium.com/code-85/a-beginners-guide-to-importing-in-python-bb3adbbacc2b
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Moduleshttps://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules
- https://developers.google.com/edu/python/introduction

(If you know what you're doing, you may actually be looking for `exec(open('filename').read())`)